# Solving a Variation of knapsack

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, knapsack-problems

I'm working on a problem which to me, seems very similar to a knapsack problem:

> A furniture store is having sale: Purchase two items at the price of the more expensive one. David went to the store and bought $2k$ items: $f_1, f_2, ...f_{2k-1}, f_{2k}$. The items are priced: $p_1, p_2,...p_{2k-1}, p_{2k}$ respectively.
>
> Help David arrange the items in pairs such that the price of the $2k$ items is minimal.
>
> Suggest an algorithm which solves the problem in $O(klogk)$. Prove correctness and running time.

So this seems very similar to the knapsack problem, but I have not been able to find a good solution.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This has no connection to knapsack.

Comment: @Raphael - I was thinking about sorting all 2k items according to their price in descending order. Then I could just go over that list and choose 2 items at a time as one tuple. this would give me $k$ tuples (or pairs). But since i am sorting $2k$ items, won't sorting take $O(2klog2k)$?

Comment: @user475680 It has nothing to do with knapsack because there are no weights, only costs. And you need to check the definition of $O()$. $O(2k\log2k)$ is exactly the same thing as $O(k\log k)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do the cases $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ for you. First, $k = 1$. Suppose there were two items, $f_1,f_2$, priced $p_1,p_2$. Without loss of generality, assume that $p_1 > p_2$. Then whatever you do, you will pay $f_1$.

When $k = 2$, there are four items $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ and four prices $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$. Suppose again that $p_1>p_2>p_3>p_4$. There are three possible ways of pairing items: $(f_1,f_2),(f_3,f_4)$, $(f_1,f_3),(f_2,f_4)$, $(f_1,f_4),(f_2,f_3)$. You will pay $f_1+f_3,f_1+f_2,f_1+f_2$, respectively. The lowest number here is the first $f_1+f_3$ (why?). So you should choose the pairing $(f_1,f_2),(f_3,f_4)$.

The general case is very similar. Try to figure out what step takes time $O(k\log k)$ (I have hidden this step in the description above), and then what is the best pairing. Try to solve it on your own.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my main thought was - Sorting all 2k items according to their $p$ in descending order, and then choosing two items at a time and inserting them into a tuple. But then wouldn't sorting take me $O(2klog2k)$? is it considered $O(klogk)$?

Comment: This is a question about asymptotic analysis then you can ask separately. If you follow the definition of big O, you will see that indeed $O(2k\log(2k)) = O(k\log k)$ since both functions differ by only a constant, i.e., $k\log k \leq 2k\log(2k) \leq Ck\log k$ for an appropriate $C > 0$.

Comment: Oh I see, alright so I was on the right path all along :) Thank you for your help!